# How to escape colon in HTML attribute with PHP rendering

Tags: php, html, drupal

I'm not sure "How to escape colon in HTML attribute with PHP rendering" is the right question, but here's the issue.

I'm implementing Events items from Schema.org and am having issues correctly rendering dates with a colon in the content attribute and it seems to be happening in the php rendering. I'm writing this in a custom Drupal blocks module.

Desired outcome is:

```
<p class="upcomingdate" itemprop="doorTime" content="2022-10-15T08:00">Sat, Oct 15th at 8:00am</p>
```

Actual outcome is:

```
<p class="upcomingdate" itemprop="doorTime" content="00">Sat, Oct 15th at 8:00am</p>
```

In the php module file, I stripped everything dynamic out and literally hardcoded it as:

```
$content .= '<p class="upcomingdate" itemprop="doorTime" content="2022-10-15T08:00">Sat, Oct 15th at 8:00am</p>';
```

Essentially, every individual colon I add to the content attribute only returns everything after the colon, which is why I'm thinking it needs to be escaped.

Some interesting behavior I tried was

```
$content .= '<p class="upcomingdate" itemprop="doorTime" content="2022-10-15T08\:00">Sat, Oct 15th at 8:00am</p>';
```

Which didn't work. It yielded the same actual outcome from before.

I tried this:

```
 $content .= '<p class="upcomingdate" itemprop="doorTime" content="2022-10-15T08\::00">Sat, Oct 15th at 8:00am</p>';
```

And got:

```
<p class="upcomingdate" itemprop="doorTime" content=":00">Sat, Oct 15th at 8:00am</p>
```

Which actually included the colon in the content attribute.

Then I thought, to try these with their corresponding actual outcomes:

```
$content .= '<p class="upcomingdate" itemprop="doorTime" content=":2022-10-15T08:00">Sat, Oct 15th at 8:00am</p>';

<p class="upcomingdate" itemprop="doorTime" content=":2022-10-15T08:00">Sat, Oct 15th at 8:00am</p>

$content .= '<p class="upcomingdate" itemprop="doorTime" content="test:2022-10-15T08:00">Sat, Oct 15th at 8:00am</p>';

<p class="upcomingdate" itemprop="doorTime" content="00">Sat, Oct 15th at 8:00am</p>

$content .= '<p class="upcomingdate" itemprop="doorTime" content="::2022-10-15T08:00">Sat, Oct 15th at 8:00am</p>';

<p class="upcomingdate" itemprop="doorTime" content="::2022-10-15T08:00">Sat, Oct 15th at 8:00am</p>
```

What is actually happening and how can I get that individual lone colon into my content attribute?

Comment: Why do you use double quotes when no interpolation is required? Use single quotes instead. Then you do not need to escape the double quotes inside. `$p = '<p class="upcomingdate" itemprop="doorTime" content="2022-10-15T08:00">Sat, Oct 15th at 8:00am</p>';`.

Comment: Okay, I changed the quotes. It however does not resolve my issue with the colon and truly is a matter of style.

Comment: There must be something different. It works in plain HTML/PHP as expected. What are you doing with `$p`? Can you show some more code, please?

Comment: Here is a screenshot where the code is behaving as I have described.
https://snipboard.io/xHJSbM.jpg

Comment: Looks like the renderer does something unusual.

Comment: This is happening both locally and on my live GreenGeeks hosting. There isn't a whole lot to the Drupal environment I've changed. I've kept it close to stock, so this seems like an issue that shouldn't be isolated to just me.

Comment: What drupal version do you use? I found this old, but fixed bug: https://www.drupal.org/project/blockreference/issues/3170849

Comment: Locally: Drupal 9.3.6 - 
GreenGeeks: Drupal 9.4.5

Answer (score 0):

This a a Drupal feature, allegedly preventing your site from XSS https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2635632, https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2544110 and a few other tickets.

I believe your only solution is to replace the colon with something else when outputting, and then revert it back when reading/using. You might be able to use an attribute named `data-content` to avoid being filtered, but given this issue is [over 10 years old](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/952964) and going through flux, totally programming round it may be best.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for :)
This is specific to values in HTML attributes, so ended up moving the iso 8601 date from the content attribute to instead be in the span element and the schema.org validator picked everything up just fine.